# List All Lesser Even Numbers

Tags: vb.net

My program needs to write all **EVEN** numbers equal to or lower than the number I enter.

This is what have so far. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles                 Button1.Click
            Dim nombre As Integer
            Dim valca As Integer
            number = Convert.ToInt16(txtnombre.Text)
            While number > 0
                number -= 1
                valca = number Mod 2
                If valca = 0 Then
                    lblreponse.Text += CStr(number) + " "
                Else
                    lblreponse.Text = " "
                End If
            End While
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Define *doesn't work*. What does the program *do* if you enter 13?

Comment: Probably it resets the content of the label at every odd number cancelling the previous output on the same label

Comment: @Steve : yes, I saw that immediately *after* writing the comment :-)

Comment: As a programmer you should really get your hands on the debugger. This tool is invaluable to solve simple problems like this. If you spend a little of your time to learn how to use it you will gain a lot more time being able to fix your problems faster

Comment: yeah i defenitly should, i always do stupid errors like this :S thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  If valca = 0 Then
      lblreponse.Text += CStr(number) + " "
  Else
      lblreponse.Text = " "
  End If
```

If the number is odd, lblreponse.Text is **overwritten** with a space. All previous data is lost.

What you want to do is probably just

```
  If valca = 0 Then
      lblreponse.Text += CStr(number) + " "
  End If
```

<sup><sup>Actually... once you get an even number, why don't continue subtracting *two* instead of one?</sup></sup>

Comment: thanks it works now! only prob is i think 0 is not an even number (right?) so how can i get rid of that?

Comment: 0 *is* an even number (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero ). But if you want to get rid of that, just stop the loop above 1: `While number > 1`. Then 3 will get through, generate 2, and be printed. 1 will not get through and won't be able to generate 0.